# Call function-pointer using only necessary arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, parameter-pack

Let's assume I have the structure `X` declared and defined like this:

```
struct X {
    int i;
    X(int i = 0) : i(i) { std::cout << "X(int i = " << i << "):   X[" << this << "]" << std::endl; }
    int multiply(int a, int b = 1) { return i * a * b; }
};
```

I want to call `X::multiply` via function-pointer. To do this, I defined a `proxy`-function:

```
template <typename ObjectType,
          typename ReturnType,
          typename... ParameterTypes>
ReturnType proxy(ObjectType * object,
                 ReturnType (ObjectType::* func)(ParameterTypes...),
                 ParameterTypes... params) {
    return (object->*func)(params...);
}
```

I use it like this:

```
int main() {
    X x(10);
    int a = 5;
    
    int r = proxy<X, int, int, int>(&x, &X::multiply, a, 2);         // proxy<...> works
    //int r = proxy(&x, &X::multiply, a, 2);                         // proxy works
    //int r = proxy2<X, int, int, int, int>(&x, &X::multiply, a, 2); // proxy2<...> does not work
    //int r = proxy2(&x, &X::multiply, a, 2);                        // proxy2 works

    std::cout << "Proxy-Test:"
              << "\na = " << 5
              << "\nr = " << r
              << std::endl;
}
```

`proxy<...>` and even `proxy` work like a charm, except that I cannot call `proxy` with only one argument although the second one should be optional. (Leaving out the right-value-argument 2 in `proxy`'s invocation will yield an error.) Of course, `proxy` is expecting *exactly* two arguments, so I also created another version of the `proxy`-function:

```
template <typename ObjectType,
          typename ReturnType,
          typename... ParameterTypes,
          typename... ArgumentTypes>
ReturnType proxy4(ObjectType * object,
                  ReturnType (ObjectType::* func)(ParameterTypes...),
                  ArgumentTypes... args) {
    return (object->*func)(args...);
}
```

This version has its types for parameters and arguments split into separate parameter-packs. Weirdly enough, invoking `proxy2<X, int, int, int, int>(&x, &X::multiply, a, 2);` makes the compiler think this invocation's ParameterTypes are (int, int, int) while ArgumentTypes are (int, int).
Equally weird is that the invocation `proxy2(&x, &X::multiply, a, 2);` works just fine.
None of those work if I leave out the right-value 2.

The problem remains: How can I call `X::multiply` with only the a-parameter, therefore without specifying b?

Comment: The second argument is only optional if you call the function by name. It is not optional if you do any kind of indirection.

Comment: "I want to call X::multiply via function-pointer." why?  I am serious; why does your problem require that specific implementation detail in the solution?  Is this a school assignment, or do you have an underlyong problem and think this is a solution to it?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think this is the underlying solution to my less minimal problem:
I use a framework for a web interface and I want to make a function that can take a layout-object-pointer and call its "addWidget"-function. But: Depending on the type of layout, this function needs additional parameters (for example when adding something into a grid: it needs at least a rowId and a columnId).
I also need to create a new unique-ptr in that function, so I made a more general function which invokes a function-pointer and a couple of functions which call this function.

Comment: Ah; then don't use a pmf, just use a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments cannot be used with calls via function pointers (pmf or otherwise) because default arguments are not a part of the function *type* and thus not a part of any function pointer.

A simple example using no templates or pmf:

```
bool getFlag();
int foo(int, int);
int bar(int, int=42);
bool flag = getFlag();
auto pf = flag ? foo : bar;

int answer1 = pf(5, 6); // ok
int answer2 = pf(5);    // ?????
```

The last line cannot be statically typechecked because its validity depends on the run-time value of `flag`. There are two viable options for any language: (1) declare the line unconditionally invalid of (2) check it at run-time. C++ as a statically typed language chooses the first option. There is no way around it. Templates or pmf do not change this fact.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I call `X::multiply` with only the a-parameter, therefore without specifying b?

You can't, intercepting the type of `X::multiply` and the types of it's arguments.

The problem is default values for functions/methods aren't part of the function signature, so when you pass a `X::multiply` pointer, the type of the method is `int (X::*)(int, int)` and the fact that the second argument is optional (with a `1` default value) is lost.

So, inside `proxy()`/`proxy2()`, you can't call `X::multiply()` with only an argument, because the compiler know that `X::multiply()` expects **two** arguments.

The usual way to solve this problem, as suggested by Yakk - Adam Nevraumont, is pass through a lambda function. This permit to use the `multiply()` method directly, avoiding it's type deduction and maintaining the knowledge of the optional argument (and of the default value).

For example, if you don't need to pass the `x` object but you can pass it inside the lambda, you can write a simple `proxy_1()` function

```
template <typename Lambda,
          typename ... ArgumentTypes>
auto proxy_1 (Lambda func,
              ArgumentTypes ... args)
 { return func(args...); }
```

that can be used as follows

```
   X   x{10};
   int a{5};

   auto l1 { [&](auto... args) { return x.multiply(args...); } };

   int r1a { proxy_1(l1, a, 2) };
   int r1b { proxy_1(l1, a) };
   int r1c { proxy_1<decltype(l1), int, int>(l1, a, 2) };
   int r1d { proxy_1<decltype(l1), int>(l1, a) };
```

On the contrary, if you need to pass function and object as separate arguments, the `proxy_2()` become a little more complicated

```
template <typename Object,
          typename Lambda,
          typename ... ArgumentTypes>
auto proxy_2 (Object obj,
              Lambda func,
              ArgumentTypes ... args)
 { return func(obj, args...); }
```

and the lambda that you have to write receive the object as an argument

```
   X   x{10};
   int a{5};

   auto l2 { [](auto obj, auto... args) { return obj.multiply(args...); } };

   int r2a { proxy_2(x, l2, a, 2) };
   int r2b { proxy_2(x, l2, a) };
   int r2c { proxy_2<X, decltype(l2), int, int>(x, l2, a, 2) };
   int r2d { proxy_2<X, decltype(l2), int>(x, l2, a) };
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
 {
   int i;

   X (int i0 = 0) : i{i0}
    { std::cout << "X(int i = " << i << "):   X[" << this << "]" << std::endl; }

   int multiply (int a, int b = 1)
    { return i * a * b; }
 };

template <typename Lambda,
          typename ... ArgumentTypes>
auto proxy_1 (Lambda func,
              ArgumentTypes ... args)
 { return func(args...); }

template <typename Object,
          typename Lambda,
          typename ... ArgumentTypes>
auto proxy_2 (Object obj,
              Lambda func,
              ArgumentTypes ... args)
 { return func(obj, args...); }

int main()
 {
   X   x{10};
   int a{5};
     
   auto l1 { [&](auto... args) { return x.multiply(args...); } };

   int r1a { proxy_1(l1, a, 2) };
   int r1b { proxy_1(l1, a) };
   int r1c { proxy_1<decltype(l1), int, int>(l1, a, 2) };
   int r1d { proxy_1<decltype(l1), int>(l1, a) };

   auto l2 { [](auto obj, auto... args) { return obj.multiply(args...); } };

   int r2a { proxy_2(x, l2, a, 2) };
   int r2b { proxy_2(x, l2, a) };
   int r2c { proxy_2<X, decltype(l2), int, int>(x, l2, a, 2) };
   int r2d { proxy_2<X, decltype(l2), int>(x, l2, a) };

   std::cout << "Proxy-Test:"
      << "\na  = " << 5
      << "\nr1a = " << r1a
      << "\nr1b = " << r1b
      << "\nr1c = " << r1c
      << "\nr1d = " << r1d
      << "\nr2a = " << r2a
      << "\nr2b = " << r2b
      << "\nr2c = " << r2c
      << "\nr2d = " << r2d
      << std::endl;
 }
```